# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::unique()

Tags: php, database, laravel-5, runtime-error, laravel-query-builder

I'm using database Query Builder in Laravel (5.5.46). In my database, one column has not unique values, so I want all the values from that column should be distinct or unique.

I used distinct() method but it discarded my repeated value. So I used unique() function. But I got this error.

```
$job_data = \DB::table('jobs')
                   ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                   ->unique('job_id')->paginate(10);
```

In database {1,1,2,3,4,2}

I expect {1,2,3,4} but I got this error

```
BadMethodCallException

Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::unique()
```

Comment: You probably want `distinct()`?

Comment: Yes and firstly I did that but no help. For `distinct()` both values came up.

Answer (score 3):

The `distinct()` method is the same as using a `DISTINCT` keyword in a query. This does not take any arguments. You can run `select(..)` then `distinct()` to get your distinctive results.

```
$job_data = \DB::table('jobs')
                 ->select('job_id')
                 ->distinct()
                 ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                 ->paginate(10);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. 
I want all columns then what should I write in `select()` ? all the columns or something else.

Comment: You can do `select('job_id', 'othercolumn', 'foo')` and so on. But keep in mind, you can still get duplicate IDs that way - because you are asking for distinct *rows*, not distinctive *IDs*. If you get multiple IDs, then the rows *are not distinct*, and some value is different. You cannot know which one to choose unless you specify more parameters.

Comment: I have two rows with having same `job_id` in the database. Now I want only one row from that table with respect to `job_id`. Is this distinct will help? or What will I do? I know I'm pretty confused.

Comment: `distinct()` will only help when the values (columns) you are selecting produce a *distinct set of rows*. By using the exact code above, it will produce that. If you start introducing more columns, it might no longer be distinct - because some values are different...

Comment: Thank you for your solution, man. One last question, `unique()` function is there in Laravel but when I'm using it, It's showing undefined then how it is used? with an example.

Comment: It's not a method of the QueryBuilder class. Its a method of the Schema class (when defining tables in a migration for example). Different classes.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry for the delay in the answer. you want to use the unique method() on a Builder. The solution is simple
To avoid this error & use pagination on collection instances, put the below code in AppServiceProvider.
First you have to use some classes:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Collection; 
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator; 
use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator;
```

Then in the boot method, put the following piece of code....

```
if (!Collection::hasMacro('paginate')) {
Collection::macro('paginate', 
function ($perPage = 15, $page = null, $options = []) {
$page = $page ?: (Paginator::resolveCurrentPage() ?: 1);
return (new LengthAwarePaginator(
$this->forPage($page, $perPage), $this->count(), $perPage, $page, $options))
->withPath('');
});
}
```

this video can help you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Se6zumUNfT4